# How do I copy a hidden folders/files from local to remote using scp?

Tags: unix

How do I copy a hidden folders/files from local to remote using scp?

I want to copy all files which is in local .bkp folder to another cluster using scp/rsync?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp /path/to/.hiddenfile user@remote.ext:/remote/path
```

(To copy a hidden dir whole)

Depending on what you exactly want to do

```
scp /path/to/.hiddendir/* user@remote.ext:/remote/path
```

(To copy all files in a hidden dir)

```
scp /path/to/.* user@remote.ext:/remote/path
```

(To copy all hidden files/ folders in a dir)